# How to add Qt libraries to visual studio

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, visual-c++-2017

I have a source with VC++ 2017
I receive the error "**Error    C1083   Cannot open include file: 'QtCore/QMap': No such file or directory**    " when i try compile the project.
I download Qt libraries and add to Include project but the problem exist.
Which directory of Qt of i had to add to project to resolve error?

this is header of my code that generate error

```
#include <QtCore/QMap>
#include <QtCore/QString>
#include <QtCore/QList>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to update your project. Go to the project properties by right-clicking on it in Solution Explorer and then select `Properties`. Then:

- In `C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories` you must set the Qt installation include path;
- In `Linker->General->Additional Library Directories` you must add the path of .libs files of your qt installation;
- In `Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies` you must put the name of .lib files that you need in order to build the project.

If it's a Qt project, you should also have the Qt plugin installed, in order to work properly with `moc` and other Qt features.

In alternative (that I suggest) you can create a CMake project and open in in Visual Studio.