# QMediaPlayer - Playing BGM Continuously in Qt

Tags: qt, qt5, qmediaplayer

I am new to Qt. I want to make a game with many different screens (e.g. Main Screen, Loading Screen...), but in a single window, switched by index in a `QstackWidget`. When switching to the Main Screen, it should play a background music continuously. Searching the web, I found `QMediaPlayer` with `QMediaPlayerlist` can do the trick. So I tried like this (using a basic `QMainWindow` to simplify the code):

**QtWidgetApplication1.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QMediaPlaylist>

class QtWidgetsApplication1 : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QtWidgetsApplication1(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    void playAudio();
    void stopAudio();

private:
    QMediaPlayer* player;
    QMediaPlaylist* playList;
};
```

**QtWidgetApplication1.cpp**

```
#include "QtWidgetsApplication1.h"

QtWidgetsApplication1::QtWidgetsApplication1(QWidget* parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    playAudio();
}

void QtWidgetsApplication1::playAudio() {
    player = new QMediaPlayer();
    playList = new QMediaPlaylist();
    playList->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("main_theme.mp3"));
    playList->setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist::CurrentItemInLoop);
    player->setPlaylist(playList);
    player->play();
}

void QtWidgetsApplication1::stopAudio() {
    player->stop();
    delete player;
    delete playList;
    player = Q_NULLPTR;
    playList = Q_NULLPTR;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "QtWidgetsApplication1.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QtWidgetsApplication1 w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**Error:**
It only plays the audio once, and shows an error message

> QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with
> QThread

**Note:**
I've tried (1.) using `QMediaPlayer` only and detecting `QMediaPlayer::endOfMedia` signal, (2.) `QSound` with a `.wav` file. First approach cannot get `QMediaPlayer::endOfMedia` signal but get `QMediaPlayer::pauseState` signal, however, I still fail to replay the audio. Second approach doesn't even play the audio and shows a `QEventLoop` error.

**Enviroment:**
Windows 10
Qt 5.15.2 MSVC2019 X64
Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (How do you open the window?)? Do you ever call `stopAudio`? Your code works perfectly on my end (Win10, Qt 5.12.6, with a WAV file), the error must be on some other part. It seems you have a second thread, or maybe you didn't start your QApplication?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I added the `main.cpp` code above. I cannot even run the code above correctly. I tried to change the file to .wav; it still played the audio for only once! I opened the window by clicking "start" button (F5) in VS. Haven't called `stopAudio()`. If you need more info, just let me know, Thank you.

Comment: @king_nak, thanks again! I have found the problem. I didn't include `QtMutiMedia` module in the right way. The approach for including modules in VS has huge different from QtCreator. I'll conclude an answerer to my post later.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `QT += multimedia` in the `.pro` file, which the projects in VS doesn't have, I tried to include those `.lib` to the project settings (Refer to [How to add Qt libraries to visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221328/how-to-add-qt-libraries-to-visual-studio)). Actually, the best way to include `QtMultiMedia` is: go to
`Extensions (in VS) > Qt VS tools > Qt Project Settings >  General > Qt Modules` and select the modules you want to include. By including the right modules, the problem I have faced has gone.